# WPF UI Update with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

Thank you for your time. I have a such a problem with WPF... it updates UI, it updates it only when the method (triggered by the button click) reaches its end. However, in my real app I need to update UI immediately to see info.

I tried to read tutorials and posts and I am ready to give up.... I would appreciate any ideas why it happens and what to do :-).

### I have a standard xaml: with a Textbox and a button:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
<Button Content="Run" Click="Button_Click" />
```

---

### Behind it

```
 public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public Person Person = new Person();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Person;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Person.FirstName = "John";
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
///// Only Here I can see the update.
        }
    }
```

---

And DataContext is:

```
    public class Person:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       private string _FirstName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set
            {
                if (_FirstName == value)
                    return;
                _FirstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");

            }
        }
....
```

Standard OnProertyChanged implementation.

Comment: Remove the `Thread.Sleep()`. You're making the UI thread sleep and thus it cannot re-render.

Comment: Hi HighCore, thank you for your answer. But this is just an emulation of my real app workflow. In the real app I have a Selenium webdriver tests and I want to notify the user about those tests. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never block the UI thread using `Sleep`.  Instead, you may want to put that part of the code on a background thread.  Eg, using Task.Factory.StartNew:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person.FirstName = "John";
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // ...
    });
}
```

Note that you can't make any other UI changes inside that thread.  If you need to, send them back to the UI thread using [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For example, as per the comment:

```
Person.FirstName = "John";
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
    foreach (string mlsNumber in ourMlses) 
    { 
        Listing listing = sourceSite.ParseByMls(mlsNumber); 
        if (listing != null) 
        { 
            var successDb = sourceSite.UpdateListing(listing); 
            if (!successDb) 
            { 
                throw new Exception("Db error"); 
            } 

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {

                // UI update that listing have been added to the DB 
            });
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Hi McGarnagle, 
Thanks a lot for your response. Sorry, for maybe not the smartest question,
            foreach (string mlsNumber in ourMlses)
            {
                Listing listing = sourceSite.ParseByMls(mlsNumber);
                if (listing != null)
                {
                  var successDb = sourceSite.UpdateListing(listing);
                    if (!successDb)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Db error"); 
                    }
                   // UI update that listing have been added to the DB

Comment: @Svitlana I've updated above ... the idea is to put the database / time-consuming tasks into the background thread, and then dispatch anything UI-related back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running a lengthy operation in `Button_Click` method and want to update UI first with a new *FirstName*. Try to wrap up your *FirstName* initialization in [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) method:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            new Action(() => {
                Person.FirstName = "John";
            }));
      // Run a lengthy operation here
 }
```

It will trigger UI update on PropertyChanged event in the same manner as it was after exiting the Button_Click method.

*P.S.* However, all code you see here is quite bad practice and I would murder a developer who wrote it. But it may suit some academic purposes. To make a proper solution, it's better to use [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) and handle it in *ViewModel* instead of click handlers.

Comment: And the last question. Can I increase a reputation of you and other people who responded?

Comment: No worries. Do two things: 1) mark the best reply as an answer of your question; 2) upvote a reply you like best (can be a time restriction between upvotes for newbies).